# Calculating cost on energy consumption

Tags: node.js, cron, database-schema

Trying to find a good way to set up a schema on the database for calculating energy cost.

I'm logging today the power consumption in a table.
The sensor is logged every hour.

```
Timestamp; Value; SensorId;
```

But now I want to calculate the cost for a month Jan-Feb.
And I was thinking of a simple table that when the cost changes under the day the function needs to handle the changes.

```
Timestamp; Value
```

The problem I see now is if the cron job or the sensor is out of sync etc it logs the value 00:03:12 how should I handle or calculate the result if the last cost change was 00:00:00. Should I split the value into two different `00:00:00` and next `00:03:12`?

Is there a way to think when you have this kind of problem?

Comment: This is either a simple accounting problem or a problem where you need to use averaging and guesswork.  The question I have is whether your measurement is an aggregated cost or instantaneous power usage measurement.

Comment: @DylanB I guess it would be aggregated cost.
The result should be a table where each row has a start value and an end value for each new cost row. So if there is only one row in the price table, the will only be one row in the result of the start and end value.

Answer (score 0):

I would have three tables.
Measurement:

```
MeasurementID,
MeasurementValue,
Timestamp
```

TotalCosts:

```
TotalCostID,
LastMeasurementID,
TimeStart,
TimeEnd, 
EstPeriodTotalCost,
CostID
```

Cost:

```
CostID,
Price,
Timestamp
```

This way when you report the data you will be able to organize it more effectively.  The simple SQL query:

```
SELECT sum(EstPeriodTotalCost) from TotalCosts WHERE (date range, etc)
```

Will pull out your accounting information.  Technically TotalCosts is an unnecessary table and you can calculate all the information you need from the other two tables, but the query to do that gets complicated and in a small system this denormalization is probably okay.  If the data gets weird you can refill TotalCosts with some kind of stored procedure.

Comment: What is LastMeasurementID for?

Comment: It is a foreign key that points to a measurement ID. Because you're calculating a row when the price changes, you need to link to the data point you are calculating for. That table could also contain a link to the previous measurement and the amount you're using to calculate cost, if you want to be explicit.